# Shell script: Remove duplicate quote (") from all strings in a file

Tags: bash, shell, file, unix, sed

I want to replace all duplicate double quotes to single double quotes from a file.

For example,

```
UPDATE TableA 
 SET country_code = ""FR"",
 WHERE name = ""A"";

UPDATE TableA 
 SET name = ""A's B""
 WHERE country_code = ""FR"";
```

to

```
UPDATE TableA 
 SET country_code = "FR",
 WHERE name = "A";

UPDATE TableA 
 SET name = "A's B"
 WHERE country_code = "FR";
```

How could I do that? Thanks!

Note: I tried this sed command to remove

```
sed -e 's/^"//g' test.sql > test_output.sql
```

However, nothing is changed.

Comment: `sed 's/""/"/g'` maybe

Comment: @Jetchisel 's command looks good. If the regex is still not matching, suspect that the quotes in the file are some codepoint other than the one you're typing in the sed command. A quick thing to try is copy/paste the quote character directly from the data into the command. Still might not match, but worth a try.

Comment: @Jetchisel already answered the question on comment. @Elaine You can just use Vim-like and execute the similar `sed` command: `%s/""/"/g`; or use as aforementioned directly from terminal: `sed -i 's/""/"/g' file.txt`.

Comment: Does "duplicate double quotes" mean the same thing as "*consecutive* double quotes"?  It seems so, but what about the quotes around an empty string?  Or a closing double quote adjacent to an opening double quote?

Comment: @John you could use `s/([^"])""([^"])/\1"\2/g` to only target isolated quote pairs

Comment: I guess, @Bohemian, but I don't see how that relates to the potential issues I raised.  Also, that particular variation would fail to make wanted substitutions on quote pairs occurring at the end of a line, and the example input does appear to contain such an occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works well..

`sed -i 's/""/"/g' your-file-name.txt`

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: Yes, It just tries to replace `("")` with `(")` and `-i` refers to in-place substitution.